# Storing values into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm trying to store randomly generated numbers into the string `newdeck`. However when I test it all the outputted numbers aren't in the random number order generated from above (i.e instead of being 5, 24,10, 33, 41. its 0,1,2,3,4,5). User inputs how many decks they want to use (`int deck`). I want to take the random number, `numvalue`, generated and store that into my array `newdeck`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the output incorrect?  `numvalue` doesn't hold a random number?  What is the value `deck`? Can you reproduce this failure with less code?  As a side note, get rid of the `goto` and `placeholder`.  Find a better way to do the same there (there are _many_ better ways than `goto`).

Comment: As a side note, "shuffling" and "drawing" are two distinct actions.  You should make distinct functions that perform each action.  It's counter intuitive that a function called `drawCard()` shuffles the deck (and only in certain situations!).

Comment: the problem im having is storing the values into my array.

Comment: numvalue is a randomnumber thats generated at every iteration of the loop. i want to take that number and put that number into an array

Comment: So, what is the value of `deck`?  If `deck == 0` then your loop is never executing at all.  If you make shuffling and drawing separate actions (and test each function individually) you will have more readable and maintainable code.

Comment: im just using this function to create a shuffle, i have a whole new function that deals the card to seperate players

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
 newdeck[numvalue] = numvalue;
```

You always put a particular card back to it's original place over and over again. And even worse: you access a non-existent element of a string.

If you want the result to be in `totaldeck` change:

```
totaldeck[numvalue] = 0;
```

(that's why you get only zeros - you put them yourself to the result...), to:

```
totaldeck[loop] = numvalue;
```

The `newdeck` variable isn't needed. To remember if a card has already been drawn you can try this:

```
std::vector<bool> drawn(52 * deck);
for (loop =0; loop < 52*deck; loop++)
{
    numvalue = rand()%(52*deck)+1;

    if (drawn[numvalue-1])
    {
        --loop;
        continue; //to be explicit
    }
    else 
    {
        suitvalue = numvalue % 4 + 1;
        drawn[numvalue-1] = true;
        totaldeck[loop] = numvalue;

        //...
```

Also, using `goto` is considered a **very bad** programming practice. The simplest way to avoid it here is given in the snippet above. However you should work on even more readable way.

And also, you should partition your code into **smaller** functions. It will be easier for you to write, understand and maintain them.

Comment: thanks for the help, im still getting the error warA1.cpp:33:16: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
    std::vector<int> newdeck;

is there a library i need to include as a header?

Comment: Im thinking that a for loop might work in this case, where it reiterates a new number everytime. any chance that would work logically?

Comment: @user3255966 Yes, you should include the `<vector>` header. And yes, you can use loops to reiterate. Seriously though, consider first partitioning your function into smaller sub functions. It will all become easier.

Comment: i cant really see how i would be able to split this function up, theres only one purpose for the function and its to shuffle the cards and store them into a string. would appreciate suggestions though. Also even with the changes above its still returning values of 0. IM SO FUSTRATED RIGHT NOW

Comment: @user3255966 Yes, it has one purpose, but it's too long. Choosing a random card is an example of a subfunction that can be separated. Anyway, check my edit.

Comment: @user3255966 Consider marking the answer as accepted if you found it helpful (putting "solved" in the title is not the customary way here - the thread will be marked as "solved" when you accept the answer). Cheers!

Comment: oh good to know, unfortunately i found a new error with this code, instead now the random numbers generated are repeating themselves. so im getting a few repeats fron the numvalue generated. do you think this could be related to the fact that i changed totaldeck[numvalue] to totaldeck[loop]?

Comment: @user3255966 Yeah I forgot about remembering already drawn cards. See my edit.